# Zeros of the second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $ f:M \rightarrow N $ be a minimal immersion (of arbitrary codimension or an hypersurface if it is necessary) and let $ |A| $ be the norm of its second fundametal form.If $ A $ is not identically zero is it true that the zeros of $ |A| $ are isolated?

If $ f:M \rightarrow R^3 $ is a minimal immersion then the conjecture above is true. Briefly this case follows from the fact that $ f $ can be locally represented as a conformal minimal immersion $ X: \Omega \subset R^2 \rightarrow R^3 $ and for conformal minimal immersions the statement above is true (see Osserman 'Minimal surfaces')

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My conjecture is that this may not be true, but in order to justify it one needs to get down to some calculations that I don't have much time to carry on. Neither I could find any relevant known fact related to that.

To make some progress in the understanding of the question I would like to post the following **incomplete** considerations, and see if they initiate a discussion that may bring us closer to the solution.

Let us consider a simpler case when $\mathrm{N} = \Bbb R^3$, and $\mathrm{M} \subseteq \Bbb R^2$, so we have a classical situation with a hypersurface $\mathrm{M}$ in the 3-dimensional Euclidean space.

The [Bonnet theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bonnet_theorem) guarantees that if $g_{i j}$ and $\mathrm{II}_{i j}$ are such that the Gauss and Codazzi equations are formally satisfied:
$$
\mathrm{R} = \mathrm{II} \wedge \mathrm{II} \tag{Gauss}
$$
$$
\nabla \wedge \mathrm{II} = 0 \tag{Codazzi}
$$
then there exist an immersion $f \colon \mathrm{M} \to \Bbb R^3$ such that $g$ is the first fundamental form of $f$, and $\mathrm{II}$ is the corresponding second fundamental form. Of course, we have to require that $g_{i j}$ is positive definite.

(Don't worry too much about the notation in the equations above. It is enough to know that treating $g$ formally as a metric tensor we can construct the corresponding Levi-Civita connection $\nabla = \nabla^g$ on $\mathrm{M}$ which (formally) has the Riemannian curvature $\mathrm{R} = \mathrm{R}^g$. Using the Euclidean metric in $\Bbb R^3$ we can raise or lower indices freely, so $\mathrm{II}$ can be thought as a vector-valued 1-form, and we can use the exterior product and the exterior covariant derivative as shown)

In components, the first and the second f.f., or their prototypes, can be written in the [classical notation](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bonnet_theorem) as matrices
$$
g = 
\begin{pmatrix}
E & G \\
G & F
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{II} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
L & M \\
M & N
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $E$, $G$, $F$, $L$, $M$, $N$ are some functions on manifold $\mathrm{M}$.

Now, let $A^{i}{}_{j} = g^{i k} \mathrm{II}_{i k}$ be the shape operator, so that $|A|^2 = A^{i}{}_{j} A^{j}{}_{i}$.

Restricting to the case of minimal manifolds ($H= g^{i j} \mathrm{II}_{i j} = 0$) gives some more polynomial conditions on variables $E$, $G$, $F$, $L$, $M$, $N$.

We also could use more linear algebra (simultaneous diagonalization of two matrices), and so on...

In general, without requiring some sort of analiticity, there is no obvious reason that we cannot make all components of $\mathrm{II}$ vanishing in a neighborhood of a point.

[To be continued if there is any interest, or new ideas pop up...]

Comment: This question was born for finding a possible extension of the following fact : if a minimal immersion $ f:M \rightarrow N $ (of any codimension) has the second fundamental form that vanishes on an open subset $ U $ it must vanishes everywhere in $ M $ (this is a consequence of Simons' equation: the second fundamental form satifies a linear elliptic equation). \\

Comment: I'm thinking about your suggestions and i'm grateful with you for them. In the same direction of this question we can ask if it is true the following (less striking) fact: for every minimal immersion (of any codimension) not totally geodesic the set of zeros of the second fundamental form has Riemannian measure zero. This fact, i think, has a relevance in the article of Schoen,Simon and Yau 'Curvature estimates for minimal hypersurfaces' (1975).

Comment: About your suggestion i'm not sure to have understood your plan. Substantially you want to consider an 'abstract second fundamental form' (that is not associated to an immersion but it satisfies the hypothesis of Bonnet theorem) that is null on a subset with an accumulation point (for example a curve) and then you want to find a minimal immersion having this form as a second fundamental form. Is it right?

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. I shall definitely find some time to think about this carefully, but currently I am close to my deadline and have to work hard on my project. Feel free to edit this, add your own answers, etc. It looks like a research level question, so it may be more relevant to crosspost it to mathoverflow.net (please give the link to this question). You may get more active response there.